# HTTP PATCH method for WebAPI

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on an implementation of the HTTP PATCH method for WebAPI. I know there are packages like JsonPatch and OData Delta for that, but they don’t work for me. JsonPatch is too complicated and OData Delta can't work with `Int32` an `Guid`.

When I send PATCH to the API I need mapping to model the class only, those properties that are in JSON.

Let's say I have model `Person`:

```
class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int? Age { get; set; }
}
```

The I send JSON using HTTP PATCH:

```
{
   "Name": "new,
   "Age":null
}
```

So, person should be updated: name set to "new" and age set to null. For that I created a `Patch` class:

```
public sealed class Patch<TModel> : DynamicObject where TModel : class {
    private readonly IDictionary<PropertyInfo, object> _changedProperties = new Dictionary<PropertyInfo, object>();
    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) {
        var propertyInfo = typeof(TModel).GetProperty(binder.Name);
        if (propertyInfo != null) {
            _changedProperties.Add(propertyInfo, value);
        }
        return base.TrySetMember(binder, value);
    }

    public void Apply(TModel delta) {
        foreach (var property in _changedProperties) {
            object value = ChangeType(property.Value, property.Key.PropertyType);
            property.Key.SetValue(delta, value);
        }
    }

    private static object ChangeType(object value, Type type) {
        try {
            if (type == typeof(Guid)) {
                return Guid.Parse((string)value);
            }
            if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {
                if (value == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
            }
            return Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
        } catch {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
[HttpPatch]
public IEnumerable<string> Patch([FromBody] Patch<Person> person) {
    person.Apply(_person);
```

I need some sugestions on how it can be improved and made safer. I do not have any idea about what kind of refactoring I can use here. How can I handle, for example, `IEnumerable` properties?